# How to create a program with linked list that destroys the nth element?

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list

I am creating a program with linked list which has a function that destroys the **nth** element of the list and instead places the element whose number is stored in the nth element.

I have created a program that creates a **linked list**, but I can't find a way that searches for the **nth** element.

```
struct elem {
    int value;
    elem* next;
};
int main() {
    elem* start = NULL, *last;
    int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    /// creating
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        elem* p = new elem; /// s1
        p->value = a[i]; /// s2
        p->next = NULL; /// s3
        if(start == NULL) start = p; /// s4a
        else last->next = p; /// s4b
        last = p; /// s5
    }
    /// printing
    elem* p = start;
    while (p) {
        cout << p->value << " ";
        p=p->next;
    }
    /// deleting
    p = start; /// 1
    while (p) {
        start = p->next; /// 2
        delete p; /// 3
        p = start; /// 4
    }
}
```

Could I get some help here please? Really struggling with linked list, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to pass the value of "n" to your main() function through a args[]

then, add a while loop, just like the printing, increment index each time you go through the linked list elements, and check if index == n, get the element value, then delete that element by calling your delete function.

it is better to put your print/delete part as separate functions, then call these functions through your main(). and you can add some checking conditions for what parameters you got from the args[]